# Synergy closing immediately

Tags: software-installation

So I'm running raspbian stretch on a raspberry pi 3 and just installed synergy to run as the client. (installed via terminal "sudo apt-get install synergy")

It was working yesterday, but now, when I open synergy, it closes immediately and I don't get to configure anything.

I uninstalled using "sudo apt autoremove synergy" then reinstalled and even rebooted but it still closes the second I open it up.

**Does anyone know what's going wrong or how I can fix it? Thank you in advance.**

EXTRA INFO (Not sure if this matters but so you have all the information)
Even when it would open yesterday, it was extremely iffy whether or not it would actually connect to my computer (Windows 10, HP Pavilion 15t). I don't know if that would have anything to do with my problems, but here it is.

Comment: I remember trying out Synergy on a Pi some time ago. I couldn't get it working within a reasonable time.

Answer (score 1):

You have to have the same version of synergy running on both computers.You may have to download and install the current version from the synergy web site.

Comment: What is wrong with the tested version from the repository?

Comment: Synergy is updated that often the version in the repository is not necessarily the latest

Comment: I doubt a version mismatch explains the instant client crash.